# What are the possible values for `jqXHR.status`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http

What are the possible values for `jqXHR.status`?

So far, I can see the following:

```
if (jqXHR.status === 0) { msg = 'Network Problem'; }
else if (jqXHR.status == 404) { msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]'; }
else if (jqXHR.status == 500) { msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].'; }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It can be anything found here.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

The `status` value is the HTTP protocol status field that http servers send on the response.

Note at this point, the [jquery ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) indicates that `status` is deprecated, and you should use `statusCode` instead.

Comment: It doesn't say anywhere that status is deprecated

Comment: In fact statusCode is a methid to pass callbacks to for each type of error you want to handle

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR):

> For backward compatibility with `XMLHttpRequest`, a `jqXHR` object will expose the following properties and methods:
>
> (...)
>
> - `status`
> - `statusText`

You can then read more about the `XMLHttpRequest` object on its [WHATWG Living Standard page](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/) or on its page at at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http.asp). The latter also provides a link to [a list of HTTP Status Messages](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmessages.asp).

Note that `jqXHR` also exposes `XMLHttpRequest`'s `statusText` attribute, which can be used to get a quick and useful error message in addition to the status code (*beware:* may be an empty string in HTTP/2).